# Javascript properties end up in loops

Tags: javascript, loops, object, properties

the following code will add the property 'id' to the object 'obj'. When calling the getter and setter there will be a console.log execution.

```js
let obj = {}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'id', {
    set: (val) => { console.log('set'); this.id = val; },
    get: () => { console.log('get'); return this.id; }
})

obj.id = 1;
// 'set'
console.log(obj.id);
// 'get'
// 1
```

I want to add the same functionality to a constructor function, but it ends up in a loop.

```js
let myObject = function(){
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
        set: (val) => { console.log('set'); this.id = val; },
        get: () => { console.log('get'); return this.id; }
    })
}

let obj = new myObject();
obj.id = 1;
// 'set'
// 'set'
// 'set'
// ...
// error
console.log(obj.id);
```

How can I solve that problem **without creating a pseudo-private variable** called '_id'?

Btw I have the same problem when using classes.

Comment: A setter is just a regulär function. Where do you think, the value should be stored, if you don't have that variable?

Comment: Where is it stored in the first example then, which is actually working? If I execute the first example in chrome, the object will be still empty even if I set the id = 1.

Comment: Since you&#39;re using arrow functions, in the global scope. 'this' refers to there to 'window'

Comment: Thank you @Thomas! I just noticed the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit strange, but it seems like setter starts to call itself recursively, so code goes to infinite loop of setter calls and then says that maximum call stack size exceeded. I can propose a solution: to define setters and getters on created instances. In this way it works as well:

```
let myObject = function(){

}

let obj = new myObject();

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'id', {
        set: (val) => { console.log('set'); this.id = val; },
        get: () => { console.log('get'); return this.id; }
    })

obj.id = 1;
console.log(obj.id);
```

**UPD:**

Also you can create some factory function, which will be add `id` property to instance automatically:

```
function objectFactory (num) {

    let myObject = function(){

    };

    let instance = new myObject();

    Object.defineProperty(instance, 'id', {
        set: (val) => { console.log('set ' + num); this.id = val; },
        get: () => { console.log('get ' + num); return this.id; }
    });

    return instance;
}


let obj = objectFactory(1);
let obj1 = objectFactory(2);
let obj2 = objectFactory(3);

obj.id = 1;
obj1.id = 1;
obj2.id = 1;

console.log(obj.id);
console.log(obj1.id);
console.log(obj2.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.



1. The question still is, why does the first example not end up in a loop?




2. Afaik the new-keyword creates a new empty object and then calls the constructor upon the new created object. This should behave like the first example.



3. With your solution I have the effort of adding the property for every created instance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found the answer. As long as you refer to _id instead of this._id there will be no value stored in the object itself.

```js
let myObj = function(){
    let _id
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
        get: () => {console.log('get'); return _id},
        set: (val) => {console.log('set'); _id = val}
    })
}

let obj = new myObj()

obj.id = 1
// -> 'set'

console.log(obj.id)
// -> 'get'
// -> 1

console.log(obj)
// -> {}
// the _id variable will not be part of the object!
```